# About a Yahoo article line

Tags: sentence-meaning

Currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/gangster-capitalism-american-theft-chinese-124740130.html) I am afraid I don't understand the bold part.

> It used to be “easy” to tell the American and Chinese economies apart. One was innovative, one made clones. One was a free market while the other demanded payments to a political party and its leadership, a corrupt wealth generating scam that by some estimates has netted top leaders billions of dollars. **One kept the talent borders porous acting as a magnet for the world’s top brains** while the other interviewed you in a backroom at the airport before imprisoning you on sedition charges (okay, that might have been both)

I think this part is talking about the American politic tactics(ways).

But I'm very afraid I don't understand what this part means.

Could anyone explain to me kindly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of the sentences, "one" refers to the United States, "the other" to China. (Actually in the second sentence, "one" is used twice and refers to each country in turn, which is another way of doing it.)

> One kept the talent borders porous acting as a magnet for the world’s top brains

So this means:

> The United States kept the talent borders porous, acting as a magnet for the world’s top brains

It reads better with a comma after "porous".

The "talent borders" means the national borders as seen from the perspective of "talent", i.e. talented individuals wanting to enter the country in order to work.

The term "magnet for the world's top brains" also refers to encouraging highly talented individuals to come and work in the United States.

Comment: Thanks! I could not help but stopping at the "talent borders" pondering what it means.