# The word "the U.S of A"

Tags: word-meaning

This is the continuous question to the [**former question.**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/260722/about-an-yahoo-article-line)

There is a passage in the same article saying,

> So goes the talent, so goes the innovation. Without this wellspring of brainpower lodging itself in America’s top innovation hubs, where exactly do we think it will go? That former aspiring Stanford or MIT computer scientist with ideas in his or her brain isn’t just going to sit by the window gazing at the horizon waiting for the moment when they can enter the gilded halls of **the U.S. of A.** It’s the internet era, and they are just going to get started on their dreams wherever they are, using whatever tools and resources they have available to them.

Is this bold word in a sense ridiculing the U.S.A? Or is there another hidden meaning? ( Just imagining, could this author be sarcastically implying that the "United" "States" "Of" "America" might not be "United" in the long run (or anymore)? )

*[**The original article**](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/gangster-capitalism-american-theft-chinese-124740130.html) "**and the American theft of Chinese innovation**"
(I'm not answering to myself. I'm just adding an info...)

I am sorry for bombarding questions. But many thank you in advance(m_m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"U. S. of A." is a colloquial and often humorous alternative to the usual abbreviation:

> **the U.S. of A.** *noun* [singular] (informal) (humorous) United States of America ([Oxford Advanced American Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/the-u-s-of-a)

This fits with the lighthearted or gently mocking tone of the phrase "gilded halls".